# Using java over WEB(http/html) protocol in loadrunner 9.52

Tags: java, http, scripting, loadrunner

I am new to the loadrunner tool, and I read somewhere that loadrunner supports Java as a scripting language.  What I am trying to do is to select the WEB(html/http) protocol, and while recording settings I am able to see only C language not Java. Can anyone tell me the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java over HTTP is for when your Java to Java interprocess communication is handled using HTTP as a transport mechanism, instead of a direct socket connection or using a solution such as CORBA or RM/I

Java as a language for LoadRunner is supported in many forms.   You can have a direct Java template virtual user or you can convert your web based virtual user (which records C by default) into VB or Java as the language.

As you are new to LoadRunner, you should expect the following

- If someone has not reviewed your core foundation skills as a performance tester, this should be done now and any gaps addressed, or have you paired with another tester with complementary foundation skills to allow you to work as a team
- Training.   You should expect training on both process and tool
- An internship.   Becoming a performance tester is no different than becoming a stone mason, a plumber, an electrician, an accountant or even a cosmetologist.  After a period of training and addressing any foundation skill gaps you should be under the tutelage of a master in he profession.  Call this your Journeyman/Apprentice phase of being a performance test professional.   Depending upon the strength of your foundation skills and the mastery of tool and concepts this period could be as short as six months or as long as a year.   If you hit a year and are still weak then it's probably better to seek a new profession.

If you have been asked to perform in this role then those who have asked should arm you for success.   The model above has a proven success rate at generating effective performance testing professionals.   Those which are successful outside of the model are rare exceptions who typically benefit from decades of solid engineering experience and rock solid foundation skills.

Expect to spend a lot of time reading the manuals, especially if you have not benefited from training nor an internship.   As someone who has been in this profession almost 20 years I can tell you that lacking a formal development model your efficiency will take a hard hit.   Those that lack solid foundation skills and have not been through training and an internship take five to ten times longer to complete core tasks related to performance testing with a lower overall quality in the deliverable.